# Combine similarly named columns

Tags: r

I am working with a `data.frame` that has similarly-named columns. There were three versions of a form, and the version is tacked onto the end of the column names, so the df looks like so:

```
var1  var2  var1x  var2x  var1y  var2z
1     2     NA     NA     NA     NA
NA     NA   1       2     NA     NA
NA     NA   1      3      NA     NA
4     NA    NA    NA      NA    7
```

So there are many columns that have the same name except for the last letter. I would like to combine these similar columns so that I end up with something like this:

```
var1   var2 
1      2
1      2
1      3
4      7
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: It is not possible for any of the variables to have more than one answer. So, for example, if var1 is 2, then var1x and var1y are NA by construction.

Comment: I'm guessing since @Alex said that there are different versions, there wouldn't be a case where two versions are non-missing.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. If all var1's are missing, NA should be returned. (This would happen if the person didn't fill out anything for the 1st question on any form, for example)

Comment: i have the same doubt : if Var1 says 2 and var1x says 3 do you want the resulting var1 column to say 5? i.e. sum of numbers?

Comment: @rawr: It _does_ have to do with column names, since you're replacing `var1` with `var1x`, not `var2x`.

Comment: or naa. just shifting over anything that is not an NA `matrix(Filter(Negate(is.na), c(t(as.matrix(dd)))), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)` no need to make it harder than it needs to be @AlexA.

Comment: @rawr: That assumes a particular ordering of the columns though, doesn't it?

Comment: `dd[, sort(names(dd))]` would be a minor detail

Comment: @rawr, would also fail if there are any rows that have all NAs or only one non NA value.

Comment: @BrodieG uh okay? it would also fail if there was one column. it was also fail for a 3-d array. it would also fail if the NAs were 0s or unicorns instead. I commented based on the example given. I didn't know I needed to fly the space shuttle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var1<-rowMeans(df[,grepl("var1",names(df))],na.rm=TRUE)
var2<-rowMeans(df[,grepl("var2",names(df))],na.rm=TRUE)
cbind(var1,var2)

     var1 var2
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    3
[4,]    4    7
```

`rowMeans()` will give NaN when all are NA

**EDITED:** changed to `rowMeans` for the new requirement of NA when all are NA. rowMeans gives NaN, which....to be fair, I simply decided was close enough to NA.

And if you have a lot of questions with multiple versions, I'd automate the whole darn thing with something like this:

```
list<-c("var1","var2")
get_col<-function(var){
  rowMeans(df[,grepl(var,names(df))],na.rm=TRUE)
}
newdf<-data.frame(do.call(cbind,lapply(list,get_col)))
names(newdf)<-list



   var1 var2
1    1    2
2    1    2
3    1    3
4    4    7
5  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm worried about the behavior if, for example, all of var1 for person 1 is missing. Then var1 and var2 won't be of the same length, and R will start recycling, right?

Comment: I'm confused. You said that `rowMeans()` will yield `NaN` when all values are `NA`, but then you said that you used `rowMeans()` because it returns `NA` when all are `NA`. That's contradictory since `NaN` != `NA`. Did you mean `rowSums()` in one of those cases?

Comment: I edited for a little clarity. I was equating, for this purpose, `NaN` to `NA`, in that it removes the behavior that `rowSums` was doing which was to give such a person `0`.

Comment: Since `NaN` and `NA` are _not_ the same, I'd recommend a step at the end to convert to `NA` using `is.finite()` or similar.

Comment: `NaN`'s are easy enough to deal with. But if I could give you bonus points for the automation edit, I would. Thanks!

Comment: And you included `na.rm=T`? As long as there is data in a single column it should work fine. And all columns are named consistently? var (in lowercase) followed by the number?

Comment: Ha! Stupid typo in the script. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another idea:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  transmute(n_var1 = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("var1")), na.rm = TRUE),
            n_var2 = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("var2")), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Which gives:

```
#  n_var1 n_var2
#1      1      2
#2      1      2
#3      1      3
#4      4      7
```

Answer (score 3):

Not that I would actually do this, but here is an answer that uses ordering (order by the first 4 chars of the variables, and then by the actual values):

```
t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) x[order(substr(names(DF), 1, 4), x)]))[, c(1, 4)]
```

Produces:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    3
[4,]    4    7
```

Should be robust to all NA.

Comment: @akrun, yes, this is very crude.

Comment: @akrun If only R allowed `f(x)` for function definitions... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to `split` the columns based on the common prefix in the column names, create a column index with `max.col` on a logical matrix (`!is.na(x1)`), `cbind` with row index (`1:nrow(x1)`) to get the non-NA elements for each row.

```
sapply(split(names(df1), sub('[^0-9]*$', '',names(df1))), function(x) {
         x1 <- df1[x]
         x1[cbind(1:nrow(x1), max.col(!is.na(x1)))]})
#     var1 var2
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    1    2
#[3,]    1    3
#[4,]    4    7
```

NOTE: This would also return `NA` if all the elements are `NA`.

Or using `splitstackshape` and `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape)
add_rownames(df1) %>%
       merged.stack(var.stub=c('var1', 'var2'), sep='var.stubs',
                   atStart=FALSE) %>%
       .[, list(var1=var1[!is.na(var1)], var2=var2[!is.na(var2)])]
#   var1 var2
#1:    1    2
#2:    1    2
#3:    1    3
#4:    4    7
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(var1 = c(1L, NA, NA, 4L), var2 = c(2L, NA, NA, 
NA), var1x = c(NA, 1L, 1L, NA), var2x = c(NA, 2L, 3L, NA), var1y = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA), var2z = c(NA, NA, NA, 7L)), .Names = c("var1", "var2", 
"var1x", "var2x", "var1y", "var2z"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```